# Remove entities after a form submit in Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to remove some entities in a form collection, depending on other submited values. Here is a minimal code of what I had in Symfony 2.5, but it doesn't work anymore with Symfony 3

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $myformentity = $options['data'];

    $builder
        ->add('mycollection', CollectionType::class)
        ->add('mycheckbox',CheckboxType::class, array(
            'required'=> false,
            'mapped'  => false,
        ));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use($myformentity) {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if($form->get('mycheckbox')->getData()){
            // Remove some entities in $myformentity->mycollection
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that even if the entities are correctly removed and the validation is correctly done after this removal, removed entites are still validated and the form submit fail.

What can I do ?

Comment: how about changing the event type your are listing to FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT

Comment: @Nickolaus : if I does that, the request data is not binded yet. For instance `$form->get('mycheckbox')->getData()` will return `false`, even if the checkbox is checked.